# for and while loop combined

Tags: python, for-loop, input, while-loop

I'm trying to add a while for my question list of constructs. I want python to only allow answers like "helemaal mee oneens, mee oneens, etc).

I understand how I make this with simple code. But I don't know how I can make all those questions only accept input from the answers I want.

There is raw input, so people have to be able to type their answer. I tried this:

```
for Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid in (list(range(0,8))):
 while Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid (list(range(0,8))) != "Helemaal niet mee eens" and != "Niet mee eens" and != "Neutraal" and != "Mee eens" and != "Helemaal mee eens":
   print ("Let op: deze vragen zijn hoofdletter gevoelig, elk antwoord dient precies overgenomen te worden.")
```

That didn't work out quite well.. It just printed a lot of "het programma is hoofdletter gevoelig. Er dient niet met hoofdletters geschreven te worden." Can anybody help me?
I'm not good at programming, i have to do this for a school assignment and i really don't get it..

```
while Welk_construct != "vriendelijkheid" and Welk_construct != "emotionele stabiliteit" and Welk_construct != "extraversie" and Welk_construct != "consciëntieusheid" and Welk_construct != "autonomie":
  print ("Let op: het programma is hoofdletter gevoelig. Er dient niet met hoofdletters geschreven te worden.")
  Welk_construct = input ("Welk construct wilt je meten? Typ hier een van de vijf constructen.")
  if Welk_construct == ("vriendelijkheid"): 
     Antwoord_V1 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [0])
     Antwoord_V2 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [1])
     Antwoord_V3 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [2])
     Antwoord_V4 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [3])
     Antwoord_V5 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [4])
     Antwoord_V6 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [5])
     Antwoord_V7 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [6])
     Antwoord_V8 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [7])
  elif Welk_construct == ("consciëntieusheid"): 
     Antwoord_C1 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [0])
     Antwoord_C2 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [1])
     Antwoord_C3 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [2])
     Antwoord_C4 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [3])
     Antwoord_C5 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [4])
     Antwoord_C6 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [5])
     Antwoord_C7 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [6])
     Antwoord_C8 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [7])
  elif Welk_construct == ("autonomie"):
     Antwoord_A1 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [0])
     Antwoord_A2 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [1])
     Antwoord_A3 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [2])
     Antwoord_A4 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [3])
     Antwoord_A5 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [4])
     Antwoord_A6 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [5])
     Antwoord_A7 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [6])
     Antwoord_A8 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [7])
  elif Welk_construct == ("extraversie"):
     Antwoord_E1 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [0])
     Antwoord_E2 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [1])
     Antwoord_E3 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [2])
     Antwoord_E4 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [3])
     Antwoord_E5 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [4])
     Antwoord_E6 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [5])
     Antwoord_E7 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [6])
     Antwoord_E8 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [7])
  elif Welk_construct == ("emotionele stabiliteit"):
     Antwoord_ES1 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [0])
     Antwoord_ES2 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [1])
     Antwoord_ES3 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [2])
     Antwoord_ES4 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [3])
     Antwoord_ES5 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [4])
     Antwoord_ES6 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [5])
     Antwoord_ES7 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [6])
     Antwoord_ES8 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [7])
```

this is the whole file:

```
# antwoorden demografische vragen
Naam = ("onbekend")
Geslacht = ("onbekend")
Leeftijd = ("onbekend")

# overige vragen
Welk_construct = ("onbekend")
Nog_een = ("onbekend")

# antwoorden Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid
Antwoord_V1 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_V2 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_V3 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_V4 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_V5 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_V6 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_V7 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_V8 = ("onbekend")

# antwoorden Vragenlijst_consiëntieusheid
Antwoord_C1 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_C2 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_C3 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_C4 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_C5 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_C6 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_C7 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_C8 = ("onbekend")

# antwoorden Vragenlijst_autonomie
Antwoord_A1 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_A2 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_A3 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_A4 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_A5 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_A6 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_A7 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_A8 = ("onbekend")

# antwoorden Vragenlijst_extraversie
Antwoord_E1 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_E2 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_E3 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_E4 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_E5 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_E6 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_E7 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_E8 = ("onbekend")

# antwoorden Vragenijst_emotionele_stabiliteit
Antwoord_ES1 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES2 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES3 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES4 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES5 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES6 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES7 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES8 = ("onbekend")


# vragenlijsten

Demografische_vragen = (["Wat is uw naam? Typ hier uw naam.", "Wat is uw geslacht? Typ hier Man, Vrouw of Anders.", "Wat is uw leeftijd? Typ hier uw leeftijd in jaren."])

Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid = (["Vraag V1: Ik heb vertrouwen in anderen. Typ hier: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", " Vraag V2: Ik gebruik en manipuleer anderen om mijn zin te krijgen. Typ hier: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag V3: Ik help anderen graag. Typ hier: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraaga V4: Ik hou van strijd en een stevige discussie. Typ hier: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag V5: Ik vind mezelf beter dan anderen. Typ hier: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag V6: Ik heb medelijden met daklozen. Typ hier: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag V7: Ik denk dat mensen in principe goede bedoelingen hebben. Typ hier: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag V8: Ik vind het niet erg om te bedriegen om hogerop te komen. Typ hier: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens."])

Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid = (["Vraag C1: Ik breng taken tot een goed einde. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag C2: Ik hou niet van wandorde en ruim graag op. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag C3: Ik hou mijn beloftes. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag C4: Ik ben een harde werker. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag C5: Ik ben altijd voorbereid. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag C6: Ik ben erg spontaan en reageer zonder na te denken. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag C7: Ik doe de dingen die k doe altijd goed. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag C8: Ik vergeet vaak dingen op de juiste plaats terug te leggen. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens."])

Vragenlijst_autonomie = (["Vraag A1: Ik heb een levendige fantasie. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag A2: Ik vind kunst belangrijk. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag A3: Ik ervaar sterke en gevarieerde emoties. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag A4: Ik verkies afwisseling oven routine. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag A5: Ik lees graag uitdagende boeken en artikelen. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag A6: Ik verkies politiek die voor verandering is en progressief. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag A7: Ik laat mijn verbeelding graag de vrije loop. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag A8: Ik zie de schoonheid van dingen die anderen niet opvallen. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens."])

Vragenlijst_extraversie = (["Vraag E1: Ik maak gemakkelijk vrienden. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag E2: Ik hou van grote feesten en bijeenkomsten. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag E3: Ik neem graag de leiding in situaties en bij gebeurtenissen. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag E4: Ik heb moeite om anderen te benaderen. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag E5: Ik hou van opwinding en spanning. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag E6: Ik ben een heel vrolijk persoon. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag E7: Ik voel me op mijn gemak bij andere mensen. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag E8: Ik praat met veel verschillende mensen op feestjes. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens."])

Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit = (["Vraag ES1: Ik maak me veel zorgen. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag ES2: Ik word snel boos. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag ES3: Ik voel me vaak verdrietig. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag ES4: Ik laat me regelmatig gaan wat betreft genieten. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag ES5: Ik ben snel in paniek. Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag ES6: Ik vrees vaak het ergste.  Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag ES7: Ik ben altijd bezig en druk met dingen.  Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens.", "Vraag ES8: Ik raak snel geïrriteerd.  Typ hieronder: Helemaal niet mee eens, Niet mee eens, Neutraal, Mee eens, Helemaal mee eens." ])



# demografische vragen
print ("Hallo! Voordat we met de vragenlijst gaan beginnen, komen er een paar vragen over u. Zo kunnen we uw gegevens het best verwerken.")
Naam = input (Demografische_vragen [0])

while Geslacht != "Man" and Geslacht != "man" and Geslacht != "Vrouw"  and Geslacht != "vrouw"and Geslacht != "Anders" and Geslacht != "anders":
  Geslacht = input (Demografische_vragen [1])

invalide = True
while invalide:
  Leeftijd = int (input (Demografische_vragen [2]))
  if Leeftijd >=16 and Leeftijd <=99:
    invalide= False
  else:
    print ("Sorry" ,(Naam),", je moet tussen de 16 en 99 zijn")



# intro vragenlijst
print ("Welkom" ,(Naam),", je gaat nu een vragenlijst invullen voor één van de Big Five persoonijkheidstrekken.")
print ("Elk onderdeel heeft 8 vragen. Deze zullen ongeveer 2 minuten duren.")
print ("Je kunt kiezen uit: vriendelijkheid, emotionele stabiliteit, extraversie, consciëntieusheid en autonomie")


# Welk construct wil je meten
while Welk_construct != "vriendelijkheid" and Welk_construct != "emotionele stabiliteit" and Welk_construct != "extraversie" and Welk_construct != "consciëntieusheid" and Welk_construct != "autonomie":
  print ("Let op: het programma is hoofdletter gevoelig. Er dient niet met hoofdletters geschreven te worden.")
  Welk_construct = input ("Welk construct wilt je meten? Typ hier een van de vijf constructen.")
  if Welk_construct == ("vriendelijkheid"):
     Antwoord_V1 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [0])
     Antwoord_V2 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [1])
     Antwoord_V3 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [2])
     Antwoord_V4 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [3])
     Antwoord_V5 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [4])
     Antwoord_V6 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [5])
     Antwoord_V7 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [6])
     Antwoord_V8 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [7])
  elif Welk_construct == ("consciëntieusheid"): 
     Antwoord_C1 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [0])
     Antwoord_C2 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [1])
     Antwoord_C3 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [2])
     Antwoord_C4 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [3])
     Antwoord_C5 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [4])
     Antwoord_C6 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [5])
     Antwoord_C7 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [6])
     Antwoord_C8 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [7])
  elif Welk_construct == ("autonomie"):
     Antwoord_A1 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [0])
     Antwoord_A2 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [1])
     Antwoord_A3 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [2])
     Antwoord_A4 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [3])
     Antwoord_A5 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [4])
     Antwoord_A6 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [5])
     Antwoord_A7 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [6])
     Antwoord_A8 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [7])
  elif Welk_construct == ("extraversie"):
     Antwoord_E1 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [0])
     Antwoord_E2 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [1])
     Antwoord_E3 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [2])
     Antwoord_E4 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [3])
     Antwoord_E5 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [4])
     Antwoord_E6 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [5])
     Antwoord_E7 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [6])
     Antwoord_E8 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [7])
  elif Welk_construct == ("emotionele stabiliteit"):
     Antwoord_ES1 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [0])
     Antwoord_ES2 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [1])
     Antwoord_ES3 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [2])
     Antwoord_ES4 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [3])
     Antwoord_ES5 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [4])
     Antwoord_ES6 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [5])
     Antwoord_ES7 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [6])
     Antwoord_ES8 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [7])

# wil je nog een construct meten?
while Nog_een != "ja" and Nog_een != "nee":
 print ("Let op: het antwoord moet expliciet ja of nee zijn en het programma is hoofdlettergevoelig.")
 Nog_een = input ("Wil je nog een construct meten? Typ ja of nee.")

# Nee
 if Nog_een == "nee":
  print ("Bedankt voor je deelname!")

 # ja
 if Nog_een == "ja":
     Welk_construct = input ("Welk construct wilt je meten? Typ hier een van de vijf constructen.")
     while Welk_construct != "vriendelijkheid" and Welk_construct != "emotionele stabiliteit" and Welk_construct != "extraversie" and Welk_construct != "consciëntieusheid" and Welk_construct != "autonomie":
      print ("Let op: het programma is hoofdletter gevoelig. Er dient niet met hoofdletters geschreven te worden.")
      Welk_construct = input ("Welk construct wilt je meten? Typ hier een van de vijf constructen.")
     if Welk_construct == ("vriendelijkheid"):
        Antwoord_V1 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [0])
        Antwoord_V2 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [1])
        Antwoord_V3 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [2])
        Antwoord_V4 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [3])
        Antwoord_V5 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [4])
        Antwoord_V6 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [5])
        Antwoord_V7 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [6])
        Antwoord_V8 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [7])
        Nog_een = input ("Wil je nog een construct meten? Typ ja of nee.")
        if Nog_een == "nee":
         print ("Bedankt voor je deelname!")
     elif Welk_construct == ("consciëntieusheid"): 
        Antwoord_C1 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [0])
        Antwoord_C2 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [1])
        Antwoord_C3 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [2])
        Antwoord_C4 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [3])
        Antwoord_C5 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [4])
        Antwoord_C6 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [5])
        Antwoord_C7 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [6])
        Antwoord_C8 = input (Vragenlijst_consciëntieusheid [7])
        Nog_een = input ("Wil je nog een construct meten? Typ ja of nee.")
        if Nog_een == "nee":
         print ("Bedankt voor je deelname!")
     elif Welk_construct == ("autonomie"):
        Antwoord_A1 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [0])
        Antwoord_A2 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [1])
        Antwoord_A3 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [2])
        Antwoord_A4 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [3])
        Antwoord_A5 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [4])
        Antwoord_A6 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [5])
        Antwoord_A7 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [6])
        Antwoord_A8 = input (Vragenlijst_autonomie [7])
        Nog_een = input ("Wil je nog een construct meten? Typ ja of nee.")
        if Nog_een == "nee":
         print ("Bedankt voor je deelname!")
     elif Welk_construct == ("extraversie"):
        Antwoord_E1 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [0])
        Antwoord_E2 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [1])
        Antwoord_E3 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [2])
        Antwoord_E4 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [3])
        Antwoord_E5 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [4])
        Antwoord_E6 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [5])
        Antwoord_E7 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [6])
        Antwoord_E8 = input (Vragenlijst_extraversie [7])
        Nog_een = input ("Wil je nog een construct meten? Typ ja of nee.")
        if Nog_een == "nee":
         print ("Bedankt voor je deelname!")
     elif Welk_construct == ("emotionele stabiliteit"):
        Antwoord_ES1 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [0])
        Antwoord_ES2 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [1])
        Antwoord_ES3 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [2])
        Antwoord_ES4 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [3])
        Antwoord_ES5 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [4])
        Antwoord_ES6 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [5])
        Antwoord_ES7 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [6])
        Antwoord_ES8 = input (Vragenlijst_emotionele_stabiliteit [7])
        Nog_een = input ("Wil je nog een construct meten? Typ ja of nee.")
        if Nog_een == "nee":
         print ("Bedankt voor je deelname!")


# opslaan antwoorden
antwoorden_demografische_vragen = [Naam, Leeftijd, Geslacht]
antwoorden_vriendelijkheid = [Antwoord_V1, Antwoord_V2, Antwoord_V3, Antwoord_V4, Antwoord_V5, Antwoord_V6, Antwoord_V7, Antwoord_V8]
antwoorden_consciëntieusheid = [Antwoord_C1, Antwoord_C2, Antwoord_C3, Antwoord_C4, Antwoord_C5, Antwoord_C6, Antwoord_C7, Antwoord_C8]
antwoorden_autonomie = [Antwoord_A1, Antwoord_A2, Antwoord_A3, Antwoord_A4, Antwoord_A5, Antwoord_A6, Antwoord_A7, Antwoord_A8]
antwoorden_extraversie = [Antwoord_E1, Antwoord_E2, Antwoord_E3, Antwoord_E4, Antwoord_E5, Antwoord_E6, Antwoord_E7, Antwoord_E8]
antwoorden_emotionele_stabiliteit = [Antwoord_ES1, Antwoord_ES2, Antwoord_ES3, Antwoord_ES4, Antwoord_ES5, Antwoord_ES6, Antwoord_ES7, Antwoord_ES8, ]

data = open("antwoorden vragenijst", "a")
data.writelines(str(antwoorden_demografische_vragen) + "\n")
data.writelines(str(antwoorden_vriendelijkheid) + "\n")
data.writelines(str(antwoorden_consciëntieusheid) + "\n")
data.writelines(str(antwoorden_autonomie) + "\n")
data.writelines(str(antwoorden_extraversie) + "\n")
data.writelines(str(antwoorden_extraversie) + "\n")
data.writelines(str(antwoorden_emotionele_stabiliteit) + "\n")
data.close()
```

Comment: Could you provide the code in its entirety?  It's not clear whether this `while` is inside the `for` or what, and for a non-Dutch speaker it's difficult to infer from context.  :)

Comment: I think the use of a 2D lists (arrays) might be helpful here.  Something like 'Antwoord_V1' is a 1D list, however, if this was replaced by a 2D list Antwoord, for each 'Welk_construct', a different index would be used.

Comment: ofcourse! Can you please tell me how i do that? Already thanks for even replying btw!

Answer (score 2):

I wish I spoke Dutch so I could understand this code well enough to be able to show you exactly how to write it more simply (I see enough copy+paste in here that I think you could shrink it down to about 1/20th of its current size), but I suspect it'd come out illegible due to the spoken language barrier, so I'll have to give general tips instead.  :)

In general, any time you find yourself doing something like this:

```
  if Welk_construct == ("vriendelijkheid"):
     Antwoord_V1 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [0])
     Antwoord_V2 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [1])
     Antwoord_V3 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [2])
     Antwoord_V4 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [3])
     Antwoord_V5 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [4])
     Antwoord_V6 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [5])
     Antwoord_V7 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [6])
     Antwoord_V8 = input (Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid [7])
```

you don't want to have 8 different named strings, you want to just have a list of 8 strings:

```
  if Welk_construct == ("vriendelijkheid"):
     antwoord = [input(question) for question in Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid]
```

If you want to validate that input matches a certain set of words, you can use an actual `set`.  You can also use functions like `lower()` to get rid of case differences.  So this:

```
while Geslacht != "Man" and Geslacht != "man" and Geslacht != "Vrouw"  and Geslacht != "vrouw"and Geslacht != "Anders" and Geslacht != "anders":
  Geslacht = input (Demografische_vragen [1])
```

can be written much more briefly as:

```
while Geslacht.lower() not in {"man", "vrouw", "anders"}:
  Geslacht = input(Demografische_vragen[1])
```

Another way to validate input as fitting a certain pattern is to use an Enum:

```
from enum import Enum
class Geslacht(Enum):
    MAN = "man"
    VROUW = "vrouw"
    ANDERS = "anders"

while True:
    try:
        geslacht = Geschlact(input(Demografische_vragen[1]))
    except ValueError as error:
        # the loop will continue and try again
        print(error)
    else:
        # geslacht is now guaranteed to be a valid Geslacht enum value
        break
```

The benefit of using an Enum is that if you typo the string somewhere, you'll get an immediate error.  If you use an IDE, enums will also autocomplete nicely (since the IDE can see the enum definition, as soon as you start typing `Geslacht.` it'll show you a list of all the valid values), and if you use `mypy`, you can have full confidence that you're always getting a valid value of a particular type, even without having to run the code and test it.

In this particular loop:

```
for Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid in (list(range(0,8))):
 while Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid (list(range(0,8))) != "Helemaal niet mee eens" and != "Niet mee eens" and != "Neutraal" and != "Mee eens" and != "Helemaal mee eens":
   print ("Let op: deze vragen zijn hoofdletter gevoelig, elk antwoord dient precies overgenomen te worden.")
```

you're reassigning `Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid`, which I don't think you want to do (that's your question list, right)?  I think you might want to do something more like:

```
for question in Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid:
    if question not in {
        "Helemaal niet mee eens",
        "Niet mee eens",
        "Neutraal",
        "Mee eens",
        "Helemaal mee eens"
    }:
        print("Let op: deze vragen zijn hoofdletter gevoelig, "
              "elk antwoord dient precies overgenomen te worden.")
```

but I don't actually know what this loop is supposed to be doing so I'm not sure how much closer that gets you.  (Should it be iterating over the answers instead?  If so, it's extra important to be putting your answers into a list instead of eight differently-named variables!)

Comment: Nice, @Samwise!  Yeah, as soon as you see multiple strings many times, or too many comparisons, there is usually a sneakier/more efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it keeps printing that is because in your first while loop, vrag met the condition specified to keep looping, and there was no place for vrag to change value into one the the strings:

```
for Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid in (list(range(0,8))):

# Because of the wile-loop, the for-loop only got to iterate once

 while Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid != "Helemaal niet mee eens" and Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheidg != "Niet mee eens" and Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid != "Neutraal" and Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid != "Mee eens" and Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid != "Helemaal mee eens":
   print ("Let op: deze vragen zijn hoofdletter gevoelig, elk antd dient precies overgenomen te worden.")
```

To fix that, change the while into a if:

```
 if Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid != "Helemaal niet mee eens" and Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheidg != "Niet mee eens" and Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid != "Neutraal" and Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid != "Mee eens" and Vragenlijst_vriendelijkheid != "Helemaal mee eens":
   print ("Let op: deze vragen zijn hoofdletter gevoelig, elk antd dient precies overgenomen te worden.")
```

Comment: What do i have to change to stop that? (i'm really a noop sorry, i have difficulties understanding coding in my own langue, let alone in english)

Comment: I added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely clean this code up a bit, to make it a) shorter and b) cleaner.

For example, you have:

```
# antwoorden Vragenijst_emotionele_stabiliteit
Antwoord_ES1 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES2 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES3 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES4 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES5 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES6 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES7 = ("onbekend")
Antwoord_ES8 = ("onbekend")
```

This could be cleaned up by using a construct like this.  Note that python uses '0' based arrays/lists:

```
Antwoord_ES=[]
for i in range(0,7):
    Antwoord_ES.append("onbekend")

print(len(Antwoord_ES))
```

You can extend this idea to more dimensions.  See here for a reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-2d-arrays-lists-the-right-way/